# Sample Size needed for study?

Tags: anova, t-test, sample

I am coming up with a sample size for one of my studies that will use four groups. I had two questions:

1) What is the difference between using a two-group t-test of equal means with alpha = 0.01 (With four groups, six comparisions will be done) vs ANOVA with alpha = 0.05?

2) For two of my intervention groups of my study, I don't have prior information that can give me an idea of the mean nor standard deviation. What should I do considering if I choose to do an ANOVA, I need these values to estimate the sample size needed.

Thanks!

Comment: If 6 comparisons will be done, why not 0.05/6, but 0.05/5?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying

Comment: There are many ways to adjust for multiple testing. One is to divide the 5% type one error rate by the number of tests. It is called Bonferronni's adjustment. In your example you only divided by 5, and that prompted me to ask that question. Perhaps I am not sure about the motivation/rationale of using 0.01.

Comment: Oh, good call! The reason for using 0.01 was to minimize error rate. Ideally I would like to use 0.05 but with 6 comparisons that's too much error. Thanks for sharing Bonferronni's adjustment. In essence, would ANOVA be better than using Bonferroni's adjustment in this case?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:** It depends on what your questions are. If it's just "does any one of the means differ from the rest?" then F-test is enough. If you'd like to further examine the mean differences by pairs, then some inflation to account for multiple testing is needed. However, the p-value threshold does not need to be as low as 0.05/6.

Just an example, let's say there are four groups with means = 1, 1, 2, 2. Standard deviation (SD) are all assumed to be 1. Power 80% and alpha 5%. We would only need 48 cases to test it.

Now, change that to t-test with alpha now = 5%/6 = 0.0083, to detect a mean difference as small as 1 unit, we'll need 27 per group, 54 total. Since there should be 4 groups, sample size will become 108.

Yet, as stated above dividing the 5% by number of tests can be too harsh. A better alternative is to seek after sample size calculator that can incorporate other less extreme form of multiple test adjustment (one of such is called PASS). For instance, Tukey's adjustment would be a possible candidate. With this adjustment the total sample size for the above scenario can be reduced to 80. For more background information about sample size in multiple comparison, I'd suggest [this article](http://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1291&context=jmasm).

**Question 2:** The best approach is to carry out a very small pilot study to get that information. The second best would be to consult the investigators of this study. While we don't have the mean estimate, the actual difference still needs to be big enough for the invention to be clinically or practically meaningful. And the researchers themselves (or the end-user of this invention) are good sources of the magnitude of that meaningful difference. Standard deviation, with some assumptions, may be based on the SDs of the other groups that you do have. Depending on the nature of the intervention, you may wish to inflate the SD somewhat to include more samples, just to be on the safer side.

Comment: Thank you so much! Clear as mud! Regarding the pilot study, what would you recommend as a sample size per group? I know Julious recommends sample size of 12 per group for a pilot study - do you think that is fine?